# How to take the square root of a dual number ($\sqrt{a + b \cdot \varepsilon}$ with $a, ~b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\varepsilon^{2} = 0$)?

Tags: calculus, hypercomplex-numbers, dual-numbers

How to take the square root of a dual number:

$\sqrt{\Xi}$ with $\begin{align*}
a, ~b &\in \mathbb{R}\\
\varepsilon^{2} &= 0\\
\varepsilon &\ne 0\\
\\
\Xi &:= a + b \cdot \varepsilon\\
\end{align*}$

My first attempt worked (at least I think so), but the second one came to nothing, but it seems to me that taking the square root of binary numbers can also be derived in a different way, which is why I am here under the question in the question and the answers to show all possibilities to the question. *(I wrote my first attempt as an answer under the question.)*

Surely the question sounds strange, because why should one calculate that at all, but let's just ask ourselves how that would work?

### My attempt $2$

My attempt $2$ was "try and hope that it works":
$$
\begin{align*}
\Xi^{2} &= \left( a + b \cdot \varepsilon \right)^{2}\\
\Xi^{2} &= a^{2} + 2 \cdot a \cdot + b \cdot \varepsilon + \left( b \cdot \varepsilon \right)^{2}\\
\Xi^{2} &= a^{2} + 2 \cdot a \cdot b \cdot \varepsilon + b^{2} \cdot \varepsilon^{2}\\
\Xi^{2} &= a^{2} + 2 \cdot a \cdot b \cdot \varepsilon + b^{2} \cdot 0\\
\Xi^{2} &= a^{2} + 2 \cdot a \cdot b \cdot \varepsilon + 0\\
\Xi^{2} &= a^{2} + 2 \cdot a \cdot b \cdot \varepsilon \\
\Xi &= \sqrt{a^{2} + 2 \cdot a \cdot b \cdot  \varepsilon}\\
a + b \cdot \varepsilon &= \sqrt{a^{2} + 2 \cdot a \cdot b \cdot  \varepsilon}\\
c := a^{2} &\wedge d := 2 \cdot a \cdot b \cdot \varepsilon\\
a = \sqrt{c} &\wedge b = \frac{d}{2 \cdot a} \cdot \varepsilon^{-1}\\
a = \sqrt{c} &\wedge b = \frac{d}{2 \cdot \sqrt{c}} \cdot \varepsilon^{-1}\\
\\
\Xi &= \sqrt{a^{2} + 2 \cdot a \cdot b \cdot  \varepsilon}\\
a + b \cdot \varepsilon &= \sqrt{c + d \cdot  \varepsilon} \quad\mid\quad a = \sqrt{c} \wedge b = \frac{d}{2 \cdot \sqrt{c}} \cdot \varepsilon^{-1}\\
\sqrt{c} + \frac{d}{2 \cdot \sqrt{c}} \cdot \varepsilon^{-1} \cdot \varepsilon &= \sqrt{c + d \cdot  \varepsilon}\\
\sqrt{c} + \frac{d}{2 \cdot \sqrt{c}} \cdot 1 &= \sqrt{c + d \cdot  \varepsilon}\\
\sqrt{c} + \frac{d}{2 \cdot \sqrt{c}} &= \sqrt{c + d \cdot  \varepsilon}\\
\sqrt{c + d \cdot  \varepsilon} &= \sqrt{c} + \frac{d}{2 \cdot \sqrt{c}}\\
\sqrt{a + b \cdot  \varepsilon} &= \sqrt{a} + \frac{b}{2 \cdot \sqrt{a}} \quad\mid\quad \left( ~~ \right)^{2}\\
a + b \cdot  \varepsilon &= \left( \sqrt{a} + \frac{b}{2 \cdot \sqrt{a}} \right)^{2}\\
a + b \cdot  \varepsilon &= a + 2 \cdot \sqrt{a} \cdot \frac{b}{2 \cdot \sqrt{a}} + \frac{b^{2}}{4 \cdot a}\\
a + b \cdot  \varepsilon &= a + b + \frac{b^{2}}{4 \cdot a}\\
b \cdot  \varepsilon &= b + \frac{b^{2}}{4 \cdot a}\\
\end{align*}
$$

But that makes no sense...

Comment: And: Could someone with enough reputation add the tag "dual-numbers" because the tag doesn't exist yet even though it's a fairly common question and this is a question about binary numbers?

Comment: Just expand $(u + v \epsilon)^2$ and determine when it equals $a + b\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From calculus, $\sqrt{1+x} = 1 + \frac{x}{2} + O(x^2)$.

With the obvious caveats on the sign of $a$, we have
$$ \sqrt{a + b\epsilon} = \pm \sqrt{a} \sqrt{1 + \frac{b\epsilon}{a}} = \pm \sqrt{a} (1 + \frac{b\epsilon}{2a} + O(\epsilon^2)). $$

Answer (score 6):

You are making things too complicated. Let $w=a+b\epsilon$ be a dual number (with $a,b$ real). We want to find the dual numbers $z$ such that $z^2=w$.

We write $z=x+y\epsilon$, with $x$ and $y$ real numbers. A short computation shows that $z^2 = x^2 + 2xy\epsilon$. Since $(1,\epsilon)$ is a base of dual numbers (as a vector space over the real numbers), we get the system

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{lcl}
x^2 & = & a \\
2xy & = & b\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

1. The first thing to remark is that, if $a<0$, then there is no solution.
2. If $a=0$ but $b\neq 0$, then the first equation implies that $x=0$, so the second equation becomes $0=b$, so no solution.
3. If $a=b=0$, then $x=0$ and $y$ can be any real number. So $0=0+0\epsilon$ has infinitely many square roots in the dual numbers.
4. Finally, if $a>0$, then $x=\pm \sqrt{a}$ and $y=\frac{b}{2x}=\pm \frac{b}{2\sqrt{a}}$, so $\omega=a+b\epsilon$ has two opposite square roots: $\pm(\sqrt{a}+\frac{b}{2\sqrt{a}}\epsilon)$

Comment: You are missing an $\epsilon$ in the final result.

Comment: @Gary It's there, it's just infinitesimal :P

Comment: @Gary: corrected, thanks

Answer (score 0):

### My attempt $1$:

I wanted to try to derive the method of taking the square root of a dual number analogously to taking the square root of complex numbers.
So I started:

** Derivation **

$$
\begin{align*}
0 &\geq k \in \mathbb{Z}\\
\varepsilon &\ne 0\\
\varepsilon^{2} &= 0\\
\varepsilon^{3} &= \varepsilon^{2} \cdot \varepsilon = 0 \cdot \varepsilon = 0\\
\varepsilon^{4} &= \left( \varepsilon^{2} \right)^{2} \cdot \varepsilon = 0^{2}= 0\\
\varepsilon^{k} &= \varepsilon^{2 + k - 2} = \varepsilon^{2} \cdot \varepsilon^{k - 2} = 0 \cdot  \varepsilon^{k - 2} = 0\\
\\
x &\in \mathbb{R}\\
\\
e^{x \cdot \varepsilon} &= \exp\left( x \cdot \varepsilon \right)\\
e^{x \cdot \varepsilon} &= \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{\left( x \cdot \varepsilon \right)^{n}}{n!}\\
e^{x \cdot \varepsilon} &= 1 + x \cdot \varepsilon + \frac{\left( x \cdot \varepsilon \right)^{2}}{2!} + \frac{\left( x \cdot \varepsilon \right)^{3}}{3!} + \frac{\left( x \cdot \varepsilon \right)^{4}}{4!} + \cdots\\
e^{x \cdot \varepsilon} &= 1 + x \cdot \varepsilon + \frac{x^{2} \cdot \varepsilon^{2}}{2!} + \frac{x^{3} \cdot \varepsilon^{3}}{3!} + \frac{x^{4} \cdot \varepsilon^{4}}{4!} + \cdots\\
e^{x \cdot \varepsilon} &= 1 + x \cdot \varepsilon + \varepsilon^{2} \cdot \left( \frac{x^{2}}{2!} + \frac{x^{3} \cdot \varepsilon}{3!} + \frac{x^{4} \cdot \varepsilon^{2}}{4!} + \cdots \right)\\
e^{x \cdot \varepsilon} &= 1 + x \cdot \varepsilon + 0 \cdot \left( \frac{x^{2}}{2!} + \frac{x^{3} \cdot \varepsilon}{3!} + \frac{x^{4} \cdot \varepsilon^{2}}{4!} + \cdots \right)\\
e^{x \cdot \varepsilon} &= 1 + x \cdot \varepsilon + 0\\
e^{x \cdot \varepsilon} &= 1 + x \cdot \varepsilon\\
\\
\Xi &= y \cdot \left( 1 + x \cdot \varepsilon \right)\\
\Xi &= y + y \cdot x \cdot \varepsilon \quad\mid\quad \Xi = a + b \cdot \varepsilon\\
a &= y \wedge b = y \cdot x\\
a &= y \wedge \frac{b}{y} = x\\
a &= y \wedge \frac{b}{a} = x\\
\\
\Xi &= y \cdot e^{x \cdot \varepsilon} \quad\mid\quad \sqrt{~~}\\
\sqrt{\Xi} &= \sqrt{y \cdot e^{x \cdot \varepsilon}}\\
\sqrt{\Xi} &= \sqrt{y} \cdot \sqrt{e^{x \cdot \varepsilon}}\\
\sqrt{\Xi} &= \sqrt{y} \cdot \left( e^{x \cdot \varepsilon} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\\
\sqrt{\Xi} &= \sqrt{y} \cdot e^{\frac{x}{2} \cdot \varepsilon} \quad\mid\quad 
e^{x \cdot \varepsilon} = 1 + x \cdot \varepsilon\\
\sqrt{\Xi} &= \sqrt{y} \cdot \left( 1 + \frac{x}{2} \cdot \varepsilon \right) \quad\mid\quad a = y \wedge \frac{b}{a} = x\\
\sqrt{\Xi} &= \sqrt{a} \cdot \left( 1 + \frac{\frac{b}{a}}{2} \cdot \varepsilon \right)\\
\sqrt{\Xi} &= \sqrt{a} \cdot \left( 1 + \frac{b}{2 \cdot a} \cdot \varepsilon \right)\\
\sqrt{\Xi} &= \sqrt{a} \cdot 1 + \sqrt{a} \cdot \frac{b}{2 \cdot a} \cdot \varepsilon\\
\sqrt{\Xi} &= \sqrt{a} + \frac{b}{2 \cdot \sqrt{a}} \cdot \varepsilon\\
\end{align*}
$$

** Proof **

$$
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\Xi} &= \sqrt{a} + \frac{b}{2 \cdot \sqrt{a}} \cdot \varepsilon\\
\sqrt{\Xi} &= \sqrt{a} + \frac{b}{2 \cdot \sqrt{a}} \cdot \varepsilon\\
\sqrt{a + b \cdot \varepsilon} &= \sqrt{a} + \frac{b}{2 \cdot \sqrt{a}} \cdot \varepsilon \quad\mid\quad \left( ~~ \right)^{2}\\
a + b \cdot \varepsilon &= \left( \sqrt{a} + \frac{b}{2 \cdot \sqrt{a}} \cdot \varepsilon \right)^{2}\\
a + b \cdot \varepsilon &= \left( \sqrt{a} + \frac{b}{2 \cdot \sqrt{a}} \cdot \varepsilon \right)^{2}\\
a + b \cdot \varepsilon &= a + 2 \cdot \sqrt{a} \cdot \frac{b}{2 \cdot \sqrt{a}} \cdot \varepsilon + \left( \frac{b}{2 \cdot \sqrt{a}} \cdot \varepsilon \right)^{2}\\
a + b \cdot \varepsilon &= a + b \cdot \varepsilon + \left( \frac{b}{2 \cdot \sqrt{a}} \cdot \varepsilon \right)^{2}\\
a + b \cdot \varepsilon &= a + b \cdot \varepsilon + \left( \frac{b}{2 \cdot \sqrt{a}} \right)^{2} \cdot \varepsilon^{2}\\
a + b \cdot \varepsilon &= a + b \cdot \varepsilon + \left( \frac{b}{2 \cdot \sqrt{a}} \right)^{2} \cdot 0\\
a + b \cdot \varepsilon &= a + b \cdot \varepsilon \quad \square\\
\end{align*}
$$

Aka the solution that I find and proved is $\sqrt{a + b \cdot \varepsilon} = \sqrt{a} + \frac{b}{2 \cdot \sqrt{a}} \cdot \varepsilon$.

Comment: $-\sqrt{a}-\frac{b}{2\sqrt{a}}\epsilon$ should also be a square root.

Comment: When you take the squre root of $\Xi$, you should write $\pm\sqrt y$.